# How to deal with dynamic Xpath selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have an Xpath like this that is changing every time I open the url

```
//*[@id="awsui-select-23"]/div/awsui-icon/span
```

What changes is the number after select as for the example:

```
//*[@id="awsui-select-41"]/div/awsui-icon/span
```

I tried to give the following xpath but it's not working

```
("//*[contains(@id, 'awsui-select-')]")
```

Can you help me understand how should I create/change the Xpath in my code so I can access the element each time the url is opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this is the xpath

```
//*[@id="awsui-select-23"]/div/awsui-icon/span
```

you are using, and digits are changing, so you can use contaons

```
//*[contains(@id,'awsui-select-')]/div/awsui-icon/span
```

or (if you want to select the first span)

```
(//*[contains(@id,'awsui-select')]/descendant::span)[1]
```

use it like this :

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'awsui-select-')]/div/awsui-icon/span")
```

**Update 1 :**

The below works for OP :-

```
(//*[contains(@id,'awsui-select')]/descendant::span)[2]
```

or

```
(//*contains(@id,'awsui-select-')]/div/awsui-icon/span)[2]
```

Comment: thank you, unfortunately this is the second element on the page with same xpath(similar xpath) it's a trigger icon and it is not working this way :(

Comment: Okay could you try this for second button `(//*[contains(@id,'awsui-select')]/descendant::span)[2]`

Comment: Or probably this ,`(//*contains(@id,'awsui-select-')]/div/awsui-icon/span)[2]`